# PHP and dataset

Tags: php

I am revising my php knowledge. I have external.js file in which there are records in it.

```
var data = [{

"id": "71002",
"fullName": "Chenz",
"title": "Mechanical Engineer",
"reportTo": "Structural Manager",
"Reportingday": "2017-01-01T09:00:00.000Z" }, .....so on
```

I need to create html/php page from this record and list all the data above. How will I achieve this thing?

Thank you.

Comment: By writing some code.  Go ahead and give it a shot.  When you're stuck on something _specific_, you can post a question about that and include what you tried, the expected result, and the actual result.

Comment: Best way you should separate this data to json file. It is easy way to share the same data in php and js code. Read about twig template engine, it is awesome https://twig.symfony.com/

Comment: http://php.net/json_decode is likely to come in handy (with some work).

Comment: I am just looking for a starting point. My brain is stuck now. I have written a code $show_data = file_get_contents('external.js');
echo $show_data;

Comment: It showed me all the data in external.js file but I need to parse it.

Comment: You'll need to use string functions (strpos, substr) to remove the javascript portion so that it's just json. Or use javascript to output the data as plain json without the `var data =`. Then process that.

Comment: Thank you guys. I am still working on it. Are there any tutorials available online?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Data:

```
var data = [{"id": "71002","fullName": "Chenz","title": "Mechanical Engineer","reportTo": "Structural Manager","Reportingday": "2017-01-01T09:00:00.000Z" },
```

Looks to be JSON.  You should look at the json_decode() and json_encode() functions.  It will convert JSON to an array and an array to JSON.  Once in an array you can easily used that to create web pages.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

```
<?php $myData = json_decode('data = [{"id": "71002","fullName": "Chenz","title": "Mechanical Engineer","reportTo": "Structural Manager","Reportingday": "2017-01-01T09:00:00.000Z" }');
```

Would allow you to call the values something like so

```
echo '<span>'.$myData->data['id'].'</span>';
```

Would return

```
<span>71002</span>
```

You can test and look at the data once in array format with something like

```
die(print_r($myData));
```

Comment: I have tried your solution to my problem and it return NULL. that data is in separate file call external.js. It also throw an error when I use $myData->data as it said that data is invalid property. I tried to import it through javascript and it work fine but I need to sort it alphabetically.

Comment: Can you give me a larger JSON sample?  Have you validated your JSON with something like https://jsonlint.com/.  What I posted was pseudo code.  I do not know your data well and it is an approximation of what you need to do.  If you get me a better sample, I can give you something more accurate.  YOu might also try $myData['data'] instead of $myData->data.  Once you do the $myData = json_decode(), do this...  die(print_r($myData)); Get me the first 10 lines of that output, then I can show you how to code it out.